# Bubble sort ignoring the first element of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

I was doing my homework but don't know why bubble sort is not working. it is making first element of the array zero due to some unknown reason.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *arr,s;
    cout<<"Enter the quantity of numbers ";
    cin>>s;
    arr=new int[s];
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number "<<i+1<<" ";
        cin>>*(arr+i);
    }
    int temp;
    for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<(s-j);k++)
        {
            if(*(arr+k)>*(arr+k+1))
            {
                temp=*(arr+k);
                *(arr+k)=*(arr+k+1);
                *(arr+k+1)=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int x=0;x<s;x++)
    {
        cout<<*(arr+x)<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the quantity of numbers 5
Enter number 1 4
Enter number 2 33
Enter number 3 22
Enter number 4 1
Enter number 5 3
0       1       3       4       22
```

I don't know why first element is getting zero. and if I run it without bubble sort loops it runs perfectly but don't with those loops.

Comment: Notice that the element missing is not the smallest one (`1`) but the largest (`33`). This implies that every element in the sorted array is shifted to the right by one. This should help you debug.

Comment: and last element is also getting ignored

Comment: @Junaid Khalid  Here if(*(arr+k)>*(arr+k+1)) is an attempt to access memory beyond the array when j is equal to 0 and k is equal to s - 1.

Comment: *due to some unknown reason* -- The reason *is* known.  So do you want to know how to find out the reason?  The way you find out is to use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset and step through your code, looking carefully at the array, indices, and which indices are being accessed.

Comment: k is getting initialised with zero and not getting decremented then how k is equals to -1?

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify array values using `*`.  Just say `arr[k]` instead of `*(arr + k)`, etc.

Comment: @JunaidKhalid Here is your code [using only 3 values, and using std::vector::at() to detect the mistake](https://www.ideone.com/rHkXPg).  The runtime error at the bottom describes exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this for loop

```
    for(int k=0;k<(s-j);k++)
    {
        if(*(arr+k)>*(arr+k+1))
                      ^^^^^^^ 
        {
            temp=*(arr+k);
            *(arr+k)=*(arr+k+1);
            *(arr+k+1)=temp;
        }
```

there is an attempt tp access memory beyond the array when `j` is equal to `0` and `k` is equal to `s - 1`. That is in this case `k + 1` is equal to `s` though the valid range of indices is `[0, s-1]`.

At least change the loops the following way

```
for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
{
    for(int k = 1;k<(s-j);k++)
    {
        if(*(arr+k) < *(arr+k-1))
        {
            int temp=*(arr+k);
            *(arr+k)=*(arr+k-1);
            *(arr+k-1)=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the index is off. You are picking up garbage values from outside your valid range (they just happen to be zeros). An easier style might help detect the problem.

```
for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
{
    for(int k=1;k<s;k++)
    {
        if(arr[k-1]>arr[k])
        {
            int temp=arr[k];
            arr[k]=arr[k-1];
            arr[k-1]=temp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int N, a[10050];
int main() {
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) scanf("%d" , &a[i]);
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        int mn = k;
        for (int i = k+1; i < N; ++i) {
            if (a[i] < a[mn]) mn = i;
        }
        swap(a[k], a[mn]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d " , a[i]);
}
```

## Explanation

In bubble sort, you swap the elements recursively.  Here is a 15-line code.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Avoid using internal headers in the example. Should add #include <cstdio> // for scanf, printf
#include <algorithm> // swap location in C++98
#include <utility> // swap location in C++11 (and later)

Comment: but #include <bits/stdc++.h> comprises of all those common headers

Comment: Yes, but it is compiler dependent. Not in the standard. I agree it makes things "easy", but not really portable.